# Specifying Sub query in FROM clause in Sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am using *Sequalize ORM* to fetch data from the database. I have below query to execute which runs fine in Postgres DB and I want to sequalize it, specifically, my query is related to how to sequalize the Sub-query part in FROM clause.

```
SELECT
  "users"."id",
  "users"."user_id" AS "peopleId",
  "users"."first_name" AS "firstName",
  "users"."last_name" AS "lastName",
  "users"."email",
  "users"."mobile",
  "users"."status"
FROM (select * from users where address_id in (select addresses_id from location_view where location = 'Some, Location, India')) as "users"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses" AS "addresses" ON "users"."address_id" = "addresses"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries" AS "addresses->countries" ON "addresses"."country_id" = "addresses->countries"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "work_info" AS "work_info" ON "users"."work_info_id" = "work_info"."id"
WHERE
  "users"."status" = 'Active'
ORDER BY
  "users"."first_name" ASC
LIMIT
  5 OFFSET 0;
```

I know we do have Sequalize.query and literal methods to achieve this where I can directly specify my sub-query in raw format, but whatever examples I have googled out basically provides a way of how I can write a raw query in WHERE or select attributes sub-query conditions.

I am unable to find a way, where I have the subquery involved of the main model I will be using to execute findAndCountAll like, in this case, it will be let's say usersModel.findAndCountAll.
Also, I need to have JOIN for some other tables from which I need to select data (Not mentioned in the query).

How can I achieve the same using Sequalize?

Comment: Provided that you can write decent SQL then is there a single reason on Earth to use the proprietary, cryptic, obscured syntax of Sequalize query builder (other query builders are no better btw) instead of standard native SQL? You _are_ thinking in relational terms anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not need a subquery at all? Here is the same query but flattened.

```sql
SELECT
  "users"."id",
  "users"."user_id" AS "peopleId",
  "users"."first_name" AS "firstName",
  "users"."last_name" AS "lastName",
  "users"."email",
  "users"."mobile",
  "users"."status"
FROM "users"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN location_view lv on "users".address_id = lv.addresses_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses" AS "addresses" ON "users"."address_id" = "addresses"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries" AS "addresses->countries" ON "addresses"."country_id" = "addresses->countries"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "work_info" AS "work_info" ON "users"."work_info_id" = "work_info"."id"
WHERE
  "users"."status" = 'Active' AND lv.location = 'Some, Location, India'
ORDER BY
  "users"."first_name" ASC
LIMIT
  5 OFFSET 0;
```

I have preserved double quoting in order to be as close to your query as possible but please note that double quotes are only needed if the name contains capital letters and/or non-alphanumeric characters.